# iOS: UIScrollView detecting Swipe Gesture

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an UIScrollView which scrolls automatically by using a timer, which scrolls every 3 seconds to the next page (kind of slideshow).

Now I want to implement a function which detects any user interaction, to cancel the timer as soon as the user interacts with the scrollview, so that he can scroll through the scrollview by himself.

What would be the best way to do this?
The ScrollView isn't subclassed and is using the UIScrollViewDelegate.

Would be glad for some hints.
Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UIScrolViewDelegate has a method to detect when the user "began" dragging:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // disable timer here
}
```

Comment: thy! this is almost the best and simplest solution for me.

Comment: Yup...this is indeed more elegant! Still, I wanted to give an alternative solution for a little extra control.