# UIScrollView - scroll or swipe?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my app I have a `UIScrollView` and I need to swipe left and right from one picture to the next, but I also need to recognize a scroll.

How do I differentiate between a scroll and a swipe with `UIScrollView`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728014/uiscrollview-paging-horizontally-scrolling-vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're actually looking for is an implementation of UIScrollView with Paging, as you do not need to handle the touch events yourself, or determine if they are scrolls or swipes.

The Apple Documentation on [Scroll Views and Paging Mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html) should help you get started

Comment: Good point! However, it seems that Scrolling Using Paging Mode requires full screen, and I'm looking for a scroller that will occupy about 30% of the screen height. Is it still possible?

Comment: Never mind - I see that I can set the height to anything I want

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `UIScrollView` Delegate Methods. ScrollView can detect different types of actions drag etc or add `swipeGesture` directly to the scroll view

StackOverflow has questions already on this

[iOS: UIScrollView detecting Swipe Gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258289/ios-uiscrollview-detecting-swipe-gesture)

[Setting up UIScrollView to swipe between 3 view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820939/setting-up-uiscrollview-to-swipe-between-3-view-controllers)

[How to recognize swipe gesture in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648967/how-to-recognize-swipe-gesture-in-uiscrollview)